# UInavigation Controller with present modalviewcontroller which is not working in UItableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I've created an app which have a table view.I need to add title and a back button for that.Here is my code in viewcontroller.m file

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender{

TableViewController *sec=[[TableViewController alloc]init];

sec.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];

self.title=@"test title";

UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sec];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
[sec release];
}
```

I need to add back button now and my title bar is not displayed.Guidance please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the navigation controller's "push...." method. In your app delegate, you create a UINavigationController, make the the window's root view, and then create an UIViewController subclass and make that the root view of the UINavigation controller. When this view appears it will have a UINavigationBar showing.

Then you create this new tableview, and your UIViewController "pushes" that view using

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Did I miss something???

Comment: i had tried the code 
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];         and got navigation bar but it scrolls along with tableview and it displayed in mid of tableview and it hides the content...